# Fixed elements jumping while scrolling with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll

I have a "next" button that scrolls for each click on it of 100% of the window height. And when it's at the bottom of the page, it scrolls to the top.
The problem is that the "next" button and the top bar have a position:fixed and sometimes, when I scroll, they are jumping. I don't understand why...
I looked on StackOverflow, saw some "solutions" but none worked. Here is my javascript and html (all simplified).

The HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body style="height:100%;width:100%">
        <header>Fixed top bar</header>
        <a>Fixed next button</a>
        <div class="content" style="height:100%;width:100%">
            <section style="height:100%;width:100%">Block1</section>
            <section style="height:100%;width:100%">Block2</section>
        </div>
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="scroll.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the js:

```
(
    function ()
    {
        var _button,
            _body,
            _window,
            MARGIN,
            MOVING;

        _window = $( window );

        _document = $( document );

        _body = $("html, body");

        _button = $('#next');

        MARGIN = 50;

        MOVING = false;




        function isScrollToBottom()
        {
            return (_window.height() + _window.scrollTop() + MARGIN) >= _document.height();
        }



        function onScroll()
        {
            if (isScrollToBottom() && !_button.hasClass('top'))
            {
                _button.addClass('top');
            }
            else if (!isScrollToBottom() && _button.hasClass('top'))
            {
                _button.removeClass('top');
            }
        }


        function scrollNext(e)
        {
            if (MOVING)
            {
                return;
            }

            var scrollTop = _window.scrollTop() + (_window.height() - ((_window.scrollTop()+1) % _window.height()));

            if (isScrollToBottom())
            {
                scrollTop = 0;
            }

            MOVING = true;

            _body.animate(
                {
                   scrollTop: scrollTop + "px"
                },
                750,
                function ()
                {
                    MOVING = false;
                }
            );

            e.preventDefault();
        }



        _window.bind('scroll', onScroll);
        _button.bind('click', scrollNext);
    }
)()
```

About CSS, the header and the a are position:fixed and have top/bottom left/right properties. And html/body/sections have a 100% (min-)height.

Hope you understand and that you'll help me :(

EDIT: http://jsfiddle.net/94wv2n6n/1/
Here is a JSFiddle, I think it will be helpful

Comment: a jsFiddle might help us...

Comment: Oh yeah... Sorry, I added a link at the bottom of my post. Thanks!

Comment: It looks fine to me, are you sure it is't an issue with your browser's rendering speed?

Comment: Actually, it doesn't happen always. In order to reproduce it, I span the "next" button, scroll manually from top to bottom and reproducing that I will have the bug. I have it sometimes but without spaming I don't have a real process to reproduce it :/

Comment: which browser? for me it looks also fine...

Comment: It's Google Chrome. My laptop is a by slow so it can be the problem. I'll look next week on my home computer if I can reproduce this bug.